# Open Ruby installed gems in editor

Tags: command-line, ruby

How to open installed gems in editor such Sublime Text or Text Mate or Atom?

I would like to do it from command line like:

`open -a Sublime\ Text\ 2 something_here`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the Ruby that comes with 10.9, gems are installed in `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/`:

```
open /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/plist-3.1.0/lib/plist/parser.rb
```

If you use a Ruby installed with Homebrew, gems are installed in `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/*/gems/`.

Comment: so, I need to search in directory `/Library/Ruby/Gems/*`?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bundler for your project, you can use `bundle open` to automatically open an installed gem in your editor as specified by the EDITOR environment variable.  For example, `EDITOR="subl -w" bundle open rake` will open the version of rake your project is using in Sublime Text.

See http://bundler.io/v1.10/bundle_open.html